# Why does it work with npm but yarn not?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

After installed packages from `package.json` with `yarn`, then starting `yarn test` I've got the following error:

```
FAIL  src/Dashboard/AppBar/Tests/AppBar.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: environment.setup is not a function

      at node_modules/jest-runner/build/run_test.js:71:23

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.478s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

When I ran with `npm i` to install packages, then run the test with `yarn test`, the test will pass.

```
 PASS  src/Dashboard/AppBar/Tests/AppBar.test.js
  ✓ renders (92ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.452s, estimated 2s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

The question is, what is the different, when I install my packages with `yarn` or `npm`.

The package.json content:

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bs-axios": "^0.0.34",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.41",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "reason-react": "^0.3.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "mlbuild": "bsb -make-world",
    "mlstart": "bsb -make-world -w",
    "mlclean": "bsb -clean-world"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bs-platform": "^2.2.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "jest": "^22.4.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try:

> If you have both `react-scripts` and `jest` in your `package.json`, delete `jest` from it. Then delete `package-lock.json`, `yarn.lock` and `node_modules`. Then run `npm install` (or `yarn` if you use it).

So if you're using yarn, run `yarn install` instead of `npm install` and try again.

From: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5119